# Why the function doesn't work slideUp jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $("div.a").click(function(){
        $(this).slideUp();
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a"> <p> aaa</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't work? The function is the same like in jquery documentation.

Comment: @Juhana: I've added that link to my standard arsenal of close links, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in script tags runs as soon as the browser parses the script tag, before the parser continues with the rest of the HTML (unles you use the `defer` or `async` attributes). So your code hooking up the event handler runs **before** the element exists, so nothing gets hooked up.

Move the `script` to the *end* of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a"> <p> aaa</p></div>
<!-- ...rest of page here... -->
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $("div.a").click(function(){
        $(this).slideUp();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

That way, the elements defined by the HTML exist as of when the script runs. More here: [*YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website*](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

If for some reason you don't control where scripts go, a second-best alternative is to use jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) callback.

Comment: why ready method is second-best?

Comment: It works, thanks but I don't get it. Then why the css properties works on a div html if the css is defined before the html.

Comment: @user1533609: Because putting scripts early in the page is an anti-pattern. `ready` is unnecessary if the scripts are at the end.

Comment: @IrinaFarcau: Because CSS and JavaScript are very different things. CSS is applied to the elements on an ongoing basis, it isn't step-by-step like program code.